# An automatic regex learner?

Tags: regex, node.js, algorithm

I have strings with recurrent pattern. Like that:

```
/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/993bcoZK7UkiqsNYpbja?t=1407502307019
/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/993bcoZK7UkiqsNYpbja?t=2222222222222
/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/993bco56465456465465a?t=333333333333
```

And also thing like that:

```
/api/bucket/53e4ce6584df65130e7ead66/data/metadata
/api/bucket/465456456456465456445456/data/metadata
/api/bucket/898989898989898989898989/data/metadata
```

And much more like that.

How would be the best way to find patterns in these strings and to aggregate them ?

Like getting some sort of json:

```
{
   pattern : "/api/bucket/*/data/metadata"
   routes : ["/api/bucket/53e4ce6584df65130e7ead66/data/metadata",
             "/api/bucket/465456456456465456445456/data/metadata",
             "/api/bucket/898989898989898989898989/data/metadata"]
}
```

Comment: better now ? I want to get some sort of regex from string that match a common pattern

Comment: I found something like this for Node.JS, a regex-trie that can generate a regex from strings.

Now I try to find an easy way to find the matching probability of string then pass them to regex-trie.

Answer (score -1):

Ok found the solution, the Aho-Corasick matching algorithm referenced in the answer is not adapted. Levenshtein distance algorithm is. If found this module for Node.JS to do that: https://github.com/jefarmstrong/sortzzy